# Transforming golden and input files in test table

Tags: go, testing, snapshot

I'm trying to find a way to create a test table from golden and input files.

I have the following dir structure:

```
pkg
|
| mypackage/
  | testdata/
    | file1.input
    | file1.golden
    | file2.input
    | file2.golden
  | mypackage_test.go
  | ...
```

I'm trying to find an efficient way to create a test table from a pair of input and golden files:

```
type test struct {
   input,
   expected string
}

func getFiles() test {
  input, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Join("testdata", fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", filename, "input")))
  expected, := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Join("testdata", fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", filename, "golden")))
  return {string(input), string(expected)}
}

func getTable() []test {
  return []test{getFiles("file1"), getFiles("file2"), getFiles("file3")}
}

func TestInputs(t *testing.T) {
  table := getTable()
  for _, tt := range table {
    // perform the test
  }
}
```

I'm not really the best at writting tests, and the code above seems a bit hacky. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying?

Comment: Do the input and golden files contain many test cases? Could you add a sample of the files? [table driven tests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests) is a good resource, in case you haven't seen it.

Comment: I suggest you use [filepath.Glob](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) to discover the files instead of listing them individually. And definitely don't ignore errors when reading the files. Pass the *testing.T to the getFiles function and fail the test if there's an error. There is a dedicated site for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).